# Jquery Countdown - Hide Multiple TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-countdown

I'm working with  [JQUERY.COUNTDOWN](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/examples.html) - and I have a problem:

its possible to work with MULTIPLES INSTANCES and HIDE a TABLE ROW at end of countdown?

I had a Table, and each Row has a "Countdown" like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------
item 1     expires in 10:10:20s   [button: GO!]
-----------------------------------------------
item 2     expires in 12:20:33s   [button: GO!]
-----------------------------------------------
item 3     expires in 22:08:53s   [button: GO!]
```

Using:

```
HTML:
<div data-countdown="2016/01/01"></div>
<div data-countdown="2017/01/01"></div>
<div data-countdown="2018/01/01"></div> 

JS:
$('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
$this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {
$this.html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));

if (event.elapsed){
$(this).html('EXPIRED');};

});
});
```

I can control the "expires in XX:XX:XXs" and change the TXT to "EXPIRED" but I had a BUTTON "GO!" for each item - and this button will remain.

Then, I need to HIDE ALL ROW.

I work with the script and I can HIDE each Row with this:

```
 $("#Job3").countdown("2015/09/07 03:43:20", function(event) {
 var format = '%H:%M:%S';
 if(event.offset.days > 0) {
  format = '%-d day%!d ' + format;
      }
 if (event.offset.seconds > 0) { 
       $("#Panel").show();
       $("#NoJob").hide();
      }       
 $(this).text(event.strftime(format));
      if (event.elapsed){
       $(this).html('Expired');
       $("#TdJob3").hide();
      if (($('table#Panel tr:visible').length) == 1) { 
       $("#Panel").hide();
       $("#NoJob").show();
      }}
  });
```

#Panel - is the TABLE

#JobXX - is the countdown div

#TDJobXX - is the TD/ROW to hide

#NoJob - is an Alert message and appears only if ALL TD are hidden. (no job available)

The problem is that I will have thousands of Rows.. If I need to create a rule for each row will be a problem.

then I need a solution to work with MULTIPLE INSTANCES and HIDE each row at end of the countdown..

Any Idea?

I don't know Jquery/JS a lot...but I read all docs, and create the solution for "single countdown".. :D

Comment: you can `slideUp()` the row once respective timer is elapsed,like this `if (event.elapsed){ $(this).slideUp();}`. you really dont need that complex logic what you have right now to hide individual rows after the timer has elapsed.

Comment: Hi dreanweiver! tks a lot for the help! I slideUp() as you said, but only the "countdown" was slideup.. the row remains..

Comment: the table structure is like this: <tr id="TdJob1">
                <td class="text-right">Item 1</td>
                <td class="text-right"><div id="Job1"></div></td>
                <td class="text-right"><a class="btn btn-default btn-sm bk-rd-off" href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Job Description</a></td>
            </tr>

Comment: <div id="Job1"></div> is the "Countdown" div.. when I aply the SlideUp - the countdown slideUp only this <div> - not the row.. I don't know how I can "call the row"

Comment: Hi @dreamweiver! Tks a lot for the help!

Comment: hey @Daniel, thats easy, just call this way, `$(this).closest('tr').slideUp();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can jQuery's `slideUp()` to hide the rows , which has the timer expired.

Since your target element for the timer is  div  with id `Job1`, which is inside the `<tr>`, you need to traverse upwards until the `<tr>` and call `slideUp()`.like this to hide the complete row.

**JS CODE:**

```
$(this).closest('tr').slideUp();
```

Ref: [jQuery .slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/)

Comment: Hello @dreamweiver ! yes! after your comment yesterday I use my brain to think about... and I read many many many ideas about... then I discover the same solution. ITS WORKS! BUT, I cannot use the slideUp() - or any other effect (I tried fade too). slideUp() and fade() "REMOVE" the entire row. But for some reason, the row is REMOVED (ok) but isnt a "OFFICIAL HIDE" row. Then when I had ZERO Rows (only the Header Row) - I Hide The Table and Show a Div with a Message about ("No more Job Avaliable").

Comment: but with SLIDEUP() or FADE() - the row was Removed (ok) - but when I Count the rows with $('table#Panel tr:visible').length the result still with all rows. ON SCREEN no more rows.. only the header row.. If I try $('table#Panel tr').length - the same happens.. Then.. to work fine for me I use:  $(this).closest('tr').hide() - or $(this).closest('tr').remove().

Comment: How can I work with Slideup or Fade? What I'm doing wrong? The solution is good - but with effect will be pretty. Any Idea? tks a lot!! Daniel

Comment: When you call `slideUp()`, it just hides the row & doesnt remove it entirely, so if you want show message like `no more jobs`  , then you need to check for the visibility of the rows & depending on that show message like this. https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/74nbyat4/1/ check this simple prototype on jsfiddle.

Comment: Hi @dreamweiver! First of all tks a lot for the help and your time! I'm really glad. Tks a lot for create this prototype! I'm doing the same logic in my script - but for some reason it didn't work...  if($('#jobPortal tr:visible').length === 0) > in my case if($('#jobPortal tr:visible').length === 1) because I have a Header TR. If I put an "effect" like slideUp or fadeOut the script fails.. but with a Hide() or Remove() - works fine. (I can Hide the table and show the alert message)

Comment: Then I tried this: if($('#jobPortal tr:visible').length === 2) - EQUAL 2.. And... WORKS! I dont know why.. but, works..  :D - You can see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aw66Lj4a/) here. Now, my doubt is whether this way is really ok. Because ===2 is very stranger for me. Maybe because the "event.elapsed" of jquery.countdown.. I dont know.. tks a lot!

Comment: well i can see that there is only one header row in table which will be static always, i dont see any other static, i'm surprised to know that `length === 2` works for you and not `length ===1`.  anyway i hope you might have figured it out urself the reason behind the same

Comment: one last thing can we close this question now,since the discussion is going beyond the question & it would be confusing for others with similar issue.

Comment: Hi @dreamweiver - tks a lot for your help! problem solved!